# OS Patch Management feature - reports important security updates available for instances after running patch job

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have set up 3 CentOS 7 VMs to test out the OS patch management feature that is now available in GCP.  I deployed the patch manager agent and the Patch Management console reports all 3 VMs have "Important / security updates available".  I then scheduled a Patch deployment job for CentOS and it ran on all 3 machines.

When I check the logs, I can see that the task began at the scheduled time and reports "No packages to update".

An hour later, the dashboard still reports: "Important / security updates available".

I have rebooted the VMs and the dashboard still has not changed and it shows 100% of the VMs requiring patching.

While I suspect that there really IS no security update available, I am not sure how we can trust the dashboard.  Further, there are no hyperlinks available for more information about what these important/security updates are so how would you even know what fixes were going to be applied if there were any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error in my own project.

I created a VM Instance with **CentOS 7**, then I created a **new patch development**,
It is worth mentioning that I used 'Minimal and Security updates’ on the Patch Config menu:

[image]

Then I received the same message:

[image]

But I was able to fix it.

I have found the following documentation: [What is included in an OS patch job?](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management#whats-in-a-patch)

Where it is mentioned that:

> For Red Hat Enterprise Linux and Centos operating systems, **you can apply all** or select from the following updates:
>
> - System updates
> - Security updates

So I created another patch development, but in this case, I didn’t select the ‘Minimal and Security updates’ I just kept it blank, in this way its select the default value, and it applies all the updates instead of only the minimal and security updates.

[image]

And it worked.

[image]

Comment: You are exactly right.  I would never have thought to uncheck both options as I figured that meant it would do nothing.   Thanks!

Comment: @TerryChambers-Onix I am stuck with this OS patch management feature. Even though I have followed all the pre-requisite but the dashboard is blank, no VMs are showing up there. I have seen a similar problem in a question but no answer yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675412/configuring-vm-manager-in-gcp. Please help